# How to stop background processes started with screen

Tags: ssh, gnu-screen

This question might have been asked before but I don't see it.

I use `screen ssh` to remotely start processes that take multiple days. I ssh in, start multiple processes in the background, and detach with CRTL+A d. I don't know why, but after a certain amount of time 'screen -r' doesn't resume the screen, although the process is still running (I can `scp` the data it's producing; all looks good). That's fine.

However, the jobs are very processing heavy and I want to be able to stop them. How do I do that? Like I said, `screen -r` doesn't work. ssh'ing in again and typing `ps` doesn't show them.

Comment: And kill -9 does not work?

Answer (score 3):

You are using `screen` the wrong way.

You should connect with `ssh` and start `screen` on the remote system (or reattach to it). On the remote system you should open a new `screen` window for each process. Thus there is no need to run them in the background.

Comment: Thanks. That makes sense. If I started the processes like above, do you know how I'd stop them?

Comment: @Qroid The first try should be `Ctrl-c` as usual. You can also kill the whole window with `^A k` which usually kills the processes which belong to this terminal (by `SIGHUP`). But the question how to kill is not related to the usage of `screen`.